# Can I do real time audio analysis with Corona SDK

Tags: real-time, signal-processing, coronasdk, audio-analysis

I'm looking at getting started with simple mobile app development. [Corona SDK](http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/) looks like a pretty nice fit for some of the ideas I'd like to toy with. I'm wondering if it is possible to do real time audio analysis with it? Could I for instance build a simple guitar tuner with Corona?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the answer is yes. It's right there on the [very page](http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/multimedia-features#Audio_Tuner) that I actually scanned before posting my question. It's also supersimple. I don't even have to write my own FFT. At least for frequency analysis it's as easy as:

```
freq = recording:getTunerFrequency()
```

I don't know about getting access to raw samples and doing your own computations on them though.

Comment: And even more audio API's just exposed the other day: http://blog.anscamobile.com/2011/07/the-secretundocumented-audio-apis-in-corona-sdk/